# how do i build dynamic linq queries at runtime using strings?

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic

[This article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/65191afd-e7c4-483d-9684-a5f267557c70/) talks about building dynamic queries using strings is it possible?

i tried

```
var ase = a.Select("NEW(activity_date as date)");
```

and it doesn't work

> The type arguments for method
>   'System.Linq.Enumerable.Select(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable,
>   System.Func)' cannot
>   be inferred from the usage. Try
>   specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.

```
C:\.....\filename.xaml.cs
```

how do i build dynamic linq queries at runtime using strings?

Comment: Scott Gu [blogged](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) about it.

Answer (score 3):

In the linq samples directory there is a cool Dynamic Linq library you can use, Scott Gu has a pretty good blog post on how to use it [here.](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can have dynamic linq queries at runtime using strings. You need to use the ObjectQuery class as mentioned [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345303.aspx) and below is the code snippet to do this:

```
string queryString =
    @"SELECT VALUE product FROM AdventureWorksEntities.Products AS product";

// Call the constructor with the specified query and the ObjectContext.
ObjectQuery<Product> productQuery2 =
    new ObjectQuery<Product>(queryString, context);

foreach (Product result in productQuery2)
    Console.WriteLine("Product Name: {0}", result.Name);
```

ObjectQuery will validate the query against the LINQ model at the runtime and throws exception if it couldn't find some of the properties you are using in the query.

Comment: where do i find the ObjectQuery i don't find System.Data.Objects after googling

Comment: just click on the MSDN document link I posted (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345303.aspx), I think it's in System.Data.Entity.dll.